# Connecting to Windows docker desktop from remote computer on same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup docker desktop on my main PC and then use docker-compose from a laptop on my network to deploy to it.

I have the "DOCKER_HOST" environment variable set on my laptop to "tcp://{ipaddress}:2375"

Unfortunately that's as far as I can get, I don't seem to be able to get docker to bind the daemon to any other ip than localhost / 127.0.0.1.  If I specify my host ip in the config json like so,

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": false,
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
  "hosts": [ "tcp://192.168.1.198:2375" ]
}
```

It just refuses to start, I've also tried 0.0.0.0 as the IP to presumably bind to all IP addresses, but can't get it to work, sometimes I get the following error,

```
Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
{"status":"error","message":"exit status 1"}

   at Docker.Core.Logging.HttpClientExceptionInterceptor.<InterceptResponseAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\HttpClientExceptionInterceptor.cs:line 26
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Logging.LoggingMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\LoggingMessageHandler.cs:line 36
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.HttpClientExtensions.<GetJsonAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\HttpClientExtensions.cs:line 16
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.LifecycleClient.<DockerStartAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\LifecycleClient.cs:line 122
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.LinuxkitDaemonStartup.<StartAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\LinuxkitDaemonStartup.cs:line 30
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__25.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 160
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 69
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<RestartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:line 272
```

I have the latest version of docker desktop installed and one thing I'm also doing is checking using netstat to see if anything is listening on port 2375 on IP 0.0.0.0 or 192.168.1.198 but I've not managed to get it to bind to anything yet other than 127.0.0.1 / ::1.

Any ideas?

---

Just as an example of another config that's not working,

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "0.0.0.0:2375"
  ]
}
```

Docker starts fine, but binds on the following

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:2375         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4940
TCP    [::1]:2375             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4940
```

I can also test IP binding using the following,

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -Port 2375  (SUCCESS)
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.1.198 -Port 2375 (FAILS)
```

Comment: NO! STOP!  Remote access to the Docker daemon is a MAJOR security issue!  Don't try this!  (Anyone who can access the socket can access any file Docker can with administrator permissions, and if it's network accessible, anyone on your network can at least read anything in your `Users` directory without any authentication or auditing; on Linux, they can trivially root the entire host.)

Comment: I'm doing this on a private network with just 1 other computer on it, mine.  It's also being used for development testing, not production.

Comment: But thanks for that information though, makes me wonder how they manage to offer remote docker services in Azure etc if the security is that bad. Or is this just limited to Docker for Windows?

Comment: The containers-in-the-cloud offerings tend to be Kubernetes, which has built in security features that makes this much safer (TLS transport with encryption, user identity, a permission model that limits what users can do).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to route between my LAN IP and the docker management port using netsh,

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=2375 listenaddress={lan ip address} connectport=2375 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

This worked for me.